# Character Class- Capitalize the first letter of each word in a string

Tags: java, string, char, bluej

I'm having trouble with a program, in which i'm supposed to accept a string input, change it to char data and then capitalize the first letter of every word in the "string" using the Character class.

The code is the following:

```
import java.util.*;
public class wrapper
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1;
        s1=input.nextLine();
        s1= s1.trim();
        int howLong= s1.length();
        int i;
        int counter;
        char ch;
        for(counter=0; counter<= howLong; counter++)
        {
            ch=s1.charAt(counter);            
            System.out.print(ch);
        }

        }
}
```

I'm just trying to change the string data to char data using a for loop at the moment, but the program won't run even though it compiles. (I'm using the BlueJ IDE)

Comment: `counter<= howLong` should be `counter< howLong`

Comment: Are you allowed to use `toCharArray()`? Not that you need it, but you might like it. Also, the _"won't run"_ part tells me that [this debugging guide](http://keysersblog.wordpress.com/2014/04/21/debugging-java-code-a-beginners-guide/) might be for you :)

Comment: I'm currently reading through the guide thanks and no the lectures have not mentioned that method.

Comment: As mentioned, it's not really necessary. And for the next part, remember to read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase(char)). I hope the guide helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have to print a statement on the screen to enter a string, or, the console wouldn't open automatically.

Copy the program below and enter it instead of your program. It'll work perfectly. The program is:

```
import java.util.*;
public class wrapper
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a string");
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1;
        s1=input.nextLine();
        s1= s1.trim();
        int howLong= s1.length();
        int i;
        int counter;
        char ch;
        for(counter=0; counter< howLong; counter++)
        {
            ch=s1.charAt(counter);            
            System.out.print(ch);
        }

        }
}
```

Hope this helped you!

Regards,

Rachit Bhargava